# Using could be with Only if/ I wish

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source - I am not good looking.

1 -> If only I could be good looking.

2 -> If only I was good looking.

What is the difference between 1 and 2 in case of using, meaning, sense?

Comment: Does that difference not exist in your language? I doubt that it does not.

Comment: What the difference do you mean?

Comment: "Good looking" doesn't mean the same as "looking good". Your sentences both sound like they mean "looking good".

"Good looking" describes someone who is naturally attractive in general, whether with make-up and nice clothes or just first thing in the morning. The only way to become good looking is to get surgery.

"Looking good" describes how someone looks now compared to how that person looks normally. If you put on make-up and dress up right, then you'll *look good*. It wont make you *good looking*.

Comment: @gotube Thank you a lot. Now I see the difference between "Good looking" and "looking good". Could you please give a explanation how to use If only I could be/If only I was with "Good looking"?

Comment: The difference between "If I could be" and "If I was/were x".

Comment: @gotube Good looking is in the eye of the beholder.  I would not get ahead of myself. If only I could look good when x.

Comment: @DmitryGroker That sounds like a second question. If you edit your question so that your sentences make sense with either "good looking" or "looking good", I'll answer this question. I'm not going to answer a different question in the comments.

Comment: @gotube I see that my explanation embarrassed you, it was not a problem to remove it

Comment: Your edits improve your question. To be clear, you're just asking about the difference between "could be" and "was" in this structure?

Comment: Yeap, in case with If only and good looking, when is it better to use I could be/I was